# Debian - deleting thousands of files

Tags: linux, debian

I have machine running Debian Squeeze with apache, mysql, php... In one of the directories there are some other dirs and way too much files more than 500k files, I tried deleting via WinSCP but it hangs. Even after more than 24 hours WinSCP is still unresponsive. In the moment I am trying to delete this directory with Putty (rm -rf dirname), but just like WinSCP it became unresponsive. Any suggestions?
Thanks!

I have root access to the machine.

Comment: Remember, rm doesn't show you what files it's deleting without the -v flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deleting the directory should work. You might run in to trouble if you are trying to delete individual files because there are so many. You are not running `rm -rf dirname/*` are you?

My guess is that you are loosing the ssh connection because of inactivity, are you sure the command was not executed correctly on the server?

In any case, a possible workaround would be to use [nohup](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup):

```
nohup rm -rf dirname
```

You can launch the command and log off, it will continue in the background.

---

UPDATE:

I found [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/37329/22222) over at U&L.SE, I recommend you have a look at it. Unfortunately, I cannot recreate your problem. I have made a directory with 2516007 files and could always delete it using `rm -rf`:

```
$ mkdir ha
$ for X in $(seq 1 10000);do touch {1..10000}_$X; done
$ ls -f ha | wc -l 
  2516007     <= I stopped before the for loop finished, but this should be enough
$ time rm -rf ha/
  real  23m11.695s
  user  0m3.540s
  sys           0m42.891s
```

So, it took 20 minutes to delete ~2 million empty files. It seems reasonable that it could take hours to delete a huge amount of non-empty files.

Anyway, some of the suggestions from the U&L question should help. Specifically this one:

```
find /delb -type f  --delete
```

or this one (slightly modified from the original)

```
find /delb -type f -print0 | xargs -0r rm -f
```

Finally, a trick you could do is delete a few files at a time. If you know that some file names start with the string "foo", others "bar" etc, do this:

```
rm -rf /delb/foo*
rm -rf /delb/bar*
```

and so on. You could also try something like this:

```
for n in {a..z}; do rm -rf /delb/$n*; done
for n in {A..Z}; do rm -rf /delb/$n*; done
for n in {0..9}; do rm -rf /delb/$n*; done
```

This last command will sequentially delete each file name beginning with each letter of the alphabet, then any file names beginning with numbers.

Comment: Another alternative would `screen` but screen isn't always included by default.

Comment: No I am not running `rm -rf dirname/*`
I will try:
`nohup rm -rf dirname`
but since this is production server, will it damage it's performance while running and how can I stop it if it fails?

Comment: It should not affect the server at all (assuming it is deleting from a local disk). You can kill it by running `killall rm` or `kill $PID` where `$PID`is the process ID.

Comment: I ran `nohup rm -rf dirname` yesterday (~18 hours ago) and logged off, right now the folder is still existing.

Comment: @sklr, weird... Is the command still running? Check with `ps aux | grep rm`. Is the directory in question a normal directory or is it a remotely mounted one? Also check if you have a file called ‘$HOME/.nohup.out`.

Comment: After `ps aux | grep rm` I found this in the output 
`root     13281 13.0  0.0   3040   520 ?        D    Feb06 163:19 rm -rf delb`
Directory name is 'delb' and it is local directory on the servers HDD.
I can't find .nohup.out

Comment: Strange, that means the command is dead... Does it work if you try and `mv` the directory? Also, sorry, I meant `~/nohup.out` not `~/.nohup.out`.

Comment: Yes, I can move and rename the directory, there is no file nohup.out.

Comment: @sklr see updated answer for some more suggestions

Comment: It might be good to add `-v` to `rm` so the progress is shown. Perhaps it can give more info on why it doesn't work (does it stall on a specific file? Is it just really slow? Etc.).

Comment: Ok, I tried `find /delb -type f  --delete` unfortunately without success. 
Then like Daniel Andersson suggested I added `-v` to `nohup rm -rf delb` and for a few seconds there was only nohup.out file in the parent dir. I have one more directory like that one, so I will try the same thing. Thank you guys!

Comment: That is a very long time, I'd check dmesg and see if rm is doing several retries because of disk fault.

Answer (score 0):

As a side not to the answer already posted. From my experience in dealing with file system that ran out of inodes. With over billion files on the file system.

The fastest way to delete / list files is using find, especially if you have thousands of files / directories. Find starts working immediately provided there is no expansion to do.

> find /path/to/be/deleted -type f --delete

Don't use `*` or any other type of command line expansion as  part of your command. `*` is executed in the terminal before it is passed to the command rm / ls etc. So your terminal sits there trying to list all the hundred thousand files before passing them to the actual command that will do the work. This is very slow.

> man bash
>   ...
>   EXPANSION
>          Expansion is performed on the command line after it has been split into
>          words.  There are seven kinds of expansion performed: brace  expansion,
>          tilde  expansion,  parameter  and variable expansion, command substitu‐
>          tion, arithmetic expansion, word splitting, and pathname expansion.
>   ...